# Rails Index Page Layout Styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, layout, styling

Building a two sided marketplace.

The issue I am having is reconciling the different lengths of Product Titles and descriptions being added to the site.

http://frnsh.co.uk is the site and can see the examples on the main page.

Took a look at the truncate method but it didn't seem to work for me.

What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: what was the issue with truncate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should limit the size of Product Title field on user input screen with 'maxlength'. 60 is a good value for your site.

```
<input type="text" name="title" maxlength="60">
```

Then set 'height' in css for '.caption H3'

```
.caption h3 {
  height: 78px;
}
```

With this height your page will be good looking.